# Returning JSON from the server: What actually happends behind the scenes?

Tags: asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, post

I'm confused about what happens when I do something like

```
$.ajax( { url : 'MyController/MyMethod',
          method : 'POST', 
          complete : function ( retjson ) { // ... } 
         } );
```

which calls

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult MyMethod()
{
      // ... 
      return Json(...);
}
```

When the JSON is floating through the air from the server to my browser, what sort of data structure is it in? Is it a string representation of `retjson` that gets unpacked behind the scenes? After all, JSON is just a notation. I'm confused about what actually flows through the airwaves or ethernet cable or whatever.

Comment: Its just a series of name/value pairs e.g. `{ somePropertyName: someValue, anotherPropertyName: anotherValue }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I understand that's what it is by the time it is in JavaScript land, but I'm wondering what happens in between the time when it's in C# land and JavaScript land.

Comment: Its just text being sent from the server to the client, just the same as html is text sent from the server to the client. The browser knows how to interpret the html and present in on the page. In the case of json, it knows how to interpret and convert it to a javascript object.

Comment: it will be a string text, which will have a JSON format, if you want to see it in actual, just F12 to your browser (or open browser's console), and see request's response

Comment: @StephenMuecke Then why is it considered bad practice to send the response from the controller as an explicitly serialized (stringified) JSON objecti, i.e. a string, and then upack it on the client side with `JSON.parse(retJsonStr)` ? Isn't that essentially doing the same thing?

Comment: It would be just unnecessary extra overhead to do so. The `Json()` method serializes your object to json, so it you first serialized it, then you would be serializing it a second time, meaning you then have to 'undo' that on the client.